# Bash script incorrectly incorporating \r into variable

Tags: bash, docker, centos, chown

I have an environment setup script which I am building in a docker container. It takes a properties file which is key=value pairs, and then goes through and uses them to create an environment. The issue I'm having is when I try to chown the user (value pulled from the properties), it is coming out as "user\r", which is throwing an error on chown.

This is being executed in a docker environment I've prepared - CentOS:7 base. The userID from the properties file is pulled, created as a user in the container, and given access to the wheel group (usermod -aG wheel $user), so they have permissions in the container.

I can strip the carriage return from this particular variable, but curious how I could avoid the issue all together / how I caused it, because I have a feeling it may be causing other, currently invisible issues.

```
#!/bin/bash

dirname=$(dirname $0)
input_properties="input-properties"
...
while read -r line; do declare -x "$line"; done <${dirname}/${input_properties}
...
$SUDO mkdir -p $log
...
$SUDO chown -R $app_user: $log
```

where $app_user and $log are from the input-properties file:

```
app_user=stackoverflow
log=/opt/program-root/logs
```

and the error is

```
chown: invalid spec: 'stackoverflow\r:'
```

Comment: The file you read from probably has carriage returns. Check with `file filename` ("with CRLF line terminators"); fix with `dos2unix filename`.

Comment: Yes, you were correct. I jumped into the file in vi and fixed the ff. Don't know why I didn't think of this when it happened previously. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your file has Windows-style line endings. Easiest fix:

```
dos2unix ./${input_properties}
```

Comment: Yes, you were correct. I jumped into the file in vi and fixed the ff. Don't know why I didn't think of this when it happened previously. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Simply tell `read` command that `\r` is part of **Input Field Separators**

```
while IFS=$' \t\r\n' read -r line; do ...
```

This is a lot quicker than using **translation** and won't alter original file.